# CSS not loading in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I deployed my app to Heroku but only the assets\images are loading. The CSS files (especially the one that contains 90% of the CSS, custom.css) are not being loaded. I precompiled the assets locally and pushed them to Heroku with no luck. Only the images are loading, not the custom.css file.

I did notice an interesting error in the Heroku log:

Started GET "/users/css/parallax-slider.css" for 77.777.777.77 at 2013-06-13 02:42:09 +0000
2013-06-13T02:42:09.016864+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/css/parallax-slider.css"):

why is it looking for the css in my users controller folder? Is this why the app can't load the custom.css file?

production.rb

```
App::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  config.assets.precompile += %w(custom.css hover.css users.css works.css styleie9.css)

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  #TODO: Edit devise mailer config
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
end
```

application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
   #Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module App
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    #Required for Heroku deployment
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

    #get precompilation working on heroku:
    #config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true

    config.serve_static_assets = false

    #Add fonts for Bootstrap theme
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")

    #Prevent passwords from being written to logs
    config.filter_parameters += [:password, :password_confirmation]
  end
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've spent two sleepless nights on this and I am completely stumped.

Thanks!
-b

EDIT 1

application.css:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

.pagination {
  background: white;
  cursor: default;
  margin-top: 20px;
  a, span, em {
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
  }
```

Routes:

```
authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'activities#index'
  end
  root :to => "home#index"
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers, :posts, :comments, :activities
    end
  end
  resources :works do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :posts
  resources :activities
  resources :reposts
  resources :comments do
    member do
      put :toggle_is_contribution
    end
    end
  resources :explore
end
```

Comment: Can you post your application.css and routes file?

Comment: Hi bruce please try my post it will work Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the assistance so far. I added application.css and routes

Answer (score 19):

Please make this changes `config.serve_static_assets = true` in your **production.rb**

Please let me know what happen.hope it will work..

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help Raja. Unfortunately this did not solve the issue

Comment: have you pushed your production.rb in heroku by git add config/enviroements/production.rb and git commit -m "", git push heroku master

Comment: Yes, I did a git add, git commit, git push, and git push heroku master after making the change

Comment: Is there something else I need to do to tell Heroku to use the production.rb file?

Comment: `config.assets.precompile += %w(custom.css hover.css users.css works.css styleie9.css)` please commented it.Actually I have faced the same issue but after fixing production.rb everything is working on my site

Comment: I commented that line, pushed the code to heroku but I'm still having the same issue

Comment: where do you store your css files in asset/stylesheets folder right?

Comment: see your application.rb again has same mistake `config.serve_static_assets = false` can you please remove it from application.rb and use it in production.rb with true not false

Comment: And in application.rb please uncomment config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

Comment: I made the above changes and the issue still remains

Answer (score 7):

Update your gemfile with

```
    *group :production, :staging do
      gem 'rails_12factor'
    end*
```

Install your bundle and push it to heroku

```
    Installing rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
    Installing rails_stdout_logging (0.0.1)
    Installing rails_12factor (0.0.2)
```

It helps me when I had same problem.

Answer (score -1):

How about making a change to application.css(.scss) (like adding new empty line) and committing that? It seems that Heroku is checking for the diff files and precompiles assets accordingly. I just happened to know it accidentally, so you can try if it helps.