# Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl no stylesheet in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the tutorial by Michael Hartl. in chapter 7 I was able to deploy to Heroku but. The Heroku version is functioning properly but it seems like some stylesheet info is missing.

Let me rephrase my question: When viewed on Heroku the website is not formatted correctly as if css is disabled.

```
in Heroku:
==========
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title> Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title> 
    <link href="/assets/application-7270767b2a9e9fff880aa5de378ca791.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script src="/assets/application-3428e82709d7645135002c8fadfafdc6.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="L4TMpZr2j2TAf1jrSThKE48aaP1P+NuVfwSXEVLheEE=" name="csrf-token" /> 
    <!--[if lt IE 9]> 
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> 
<![endif]--> 
  </head> 

On the local server:
====================
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title> Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title> 
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/users.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/static_pages.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/users.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="pF9wfBsOh4j+WMjnd/sbfq+sIPxNBhiNI6lYXUycMjo=" name="csrf-token" /> 
    <!--[if lt IE 9]> 
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> 
<![endif]--> 
  </head>
```

Comment: ok... do you also have a question to go with that wall of code?

Comment: this is not how SO works, you should specify the problem

Answer (score 2):

In production, all you css is compressed, its `Fingerprinting`  :

```
    <link href="/assets/application-7270767b2a9e9fff880aa5de378ca791.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

> Fingerprinting is a technique that makes the name of a file dependent on the contents of the file. When the file contents change, the filename is also changed. For content that is static or infrequently changed, this provides an easy way to tell whether two versions of a file are identical, even across different servers or deployment dates.
>
> Fingerprinting is enabled by default for production and disabled for all other environments

[Read more about Fingerpriting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: Yep, this is explained in the Rails Tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-5_2_1_4

Answer (score 1):

I looked up another thread and the entry below in production.rb  (set to true instead of default false) fixed the issue for me.

config.serve_static_assets = true

(See also [CSS not loading in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078518/css-not-loading-in-heroku))